# Thymeleaf как добавлять элементы в коллекцию через input

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, коллекции, thymeleaf

Делаю приложение на Spring Boot с использованием Thymeleaf.

В представлении есть форма с несколькими полями для ввода типа `<input type="file"/>`.

Мне нужно, чтобы при вводе значения (загрузке файла) в это поле оно добавлялось в коллекцию List и с формой отправлялось на сервер. Как это реализовать в Thymeleaf'е?

Коллекцию могу передать через `model.addAttribute()`, но я не знаю как с ней взаимодействовать на уровне представления Thymeleaf'а.

Я придумал, как это сделать с массивом, обращаясь к каждому элементу массива по индексу, например `<input type="file" th:field="*{pictures[0]}"/>`, но мне нужен динамический размер.

Я знаю, что прямо из представления Thymeleaf можно вызывать методы, например `.add()`, но как тогда указать Thymeleaf'у, что нужно добавить именно текущий элемент из этого `input`'а? Может быть что-то с `th:with` или `th:name` или `th:value`? В общем надеюсь на помощь.

На всякий случай вот нынешняя реализация с массивом:

```
<form th:method="POST" th:action="@{/admin/addProduct}" th:object="${product}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Название: <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/>
    <br>
    Добавьте до 5-и изображений:
    1: <input type="file" th:field="*{pictures[0]}"/>
    2: <input type="file" th:field="*{pictures[1]}"/>
    3: <input type="file" th:field="*{pictures[2]}"/>
    4: <input type="file" th:field="*{pictures[3]}"/>
    5: <input type="file" th:field="*{pictures[4]}"/>
    <br>
    Цена: <input type="number" th:field="*{price}"/> руб.
    Описание: <input type="text" th:field="*{description}"/>
    Остаток: <input type="number" th:field="*{stock}"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Готово"/>
    </form>
```

Сущность Product:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private int price;
    private int stock;
    @Transient
    private MultipartFile[] pictures = new MultipartFile[5];
    private String[] picturesPath = new String[5];
    
    public Product() {}
```